# AdMob close button conflicts with status bar on iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7, admob

I have issue with status bar, because it overlay my close button on ads.

I show ads using this method

```
    [splashInterstitial_ loadAndDisplayRequest:[self createRequest]
                                   usingWindow:self.window
                                  initialImage:image];
```

so then I see next:

[image]

as you can see close button conflicts with status bar.

How to remove admob status bar on iOS 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to preserve the iOS 6 style status bar layout. The status bar will always overlap your application on iOS 7

Refer this link
http://www.appcoda.com/customize-navigation-status-bar-ios-7/

http://blog.jaredsinclair.com/post/61507315630/wrestling-with-status-bars-and-navigation-bars-on-ios-7

Comment: I know how to hide bar using this method -(BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
but how can I add it to the admob viewcontroller?

Comment: you can set the status bar style by using the UIApplication statusBarStyle method. But first you’ll need to opt out the “View controller-based status bar appearance”. Under the Info tab of the project target, insert a new key named “View controller-based status bar appearance” and set the value to NO.In any case you want to hide the status bar, you can override the prefersStatusBarHidden: in your controller:

- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return YES;
}

Comment: seems View controller-based status bar appearance - NO solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

goto your application-Info.plist and add View controller-based status bar appearance set NO